# Confirm Dialog Passing in Callback for Action

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

for my laravel app on bootstrap 3 I am attempting to do a basic application wide confirm dialog box using the code below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
     data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#confirmActionModal" 
     data-backdrop="false"
     data-title="Cancel Subscription" 
     data-body="Please confirm the cancellation of your subscription."
     data-modal-primary-button-text="Cancel Subscription"
>
   Cancel Subscription
</button>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmActionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"> Default Title </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
                Default Body
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Default Button Text</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#confirmActionModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget) ;// Button that triggered the modal
            var modalTitle = button.data('title'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
            var modalBody = button.data('body');
            var modalActionButtonText = button.data('modal-primary-button-text');
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-title').text(modalTitle);
            modal.find('.modal-body').text(modalBody);
            modal.find('.btn-primary').text(modalActionButtonText);
        })
```

Since the confirm dialog is generic across the application, I would like the ability to pass in the call back ajax function name also. So for instance when someone clicks the primary action button (in this case cancel subscription), I would like to also pass in the ajax call back as I am passing in title and body for a javascript function like cancelSubscription() that basically does the action. Any tips or is my approach flawed?

Comment: Where is you jQuery function located? Is it in a blade template or a central js include file?

Comment: blade template for now. Was going to move it to a JS file later.

Comment: Are we looking at a scenario where you could have potentially multiple modals on the same view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the ability to pass variables to the either the JQuery function or the html markup via your controllers. For example:

**PageController.php**

```
public function page()
{
    return view('template', [
        'ajax-function' => "myAjaxFunctionName"
    ]);
}
```

**template.blade.php**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
     data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#confirmActionModal" 
     data-backdrop="false"
     data-title="Cancel Subscription" 
     data-body="Please confirm the cancellation of your subscription."
     data-modal-primary-button-text="Cancel Subscription"
     data-ajax-function="{!! $ajax-function !!}"
>
   Cancel Subscription
</button>
```

You could therefore use your controller to determine the name of each function you wish to use.